# Extract ID3 tags of a MP3 URL using python

Tags: python, url, mime-types, urllib2, id3

I am developing a python program which can extract ID3 tags of mp3 files. I am using urllib2 for checking MIME type of the URL (if it is audio/mpeg), after that I need to find information about this MP3 file.

Problem is, I dont want to load that Mp3 file completely in my PC, I just want to extract ID3 tags? so is it possible to extract them without downloading MP3 file completely because downloading will slow down my process?

Please suggest something.

Thanks,

Comment: FYI it is going to be a lot easier to do ID3v2 tags only, because they're a header ... just download enough data to get the tag length, download those bytes, then close the connection. ID3v1 tags are footers at the end of the file so if you need those too, it'll be more complicated. ID3v2 is variable-length (up to 256 M) and the spec's here: http://www.id3.org/

Comment: Have you successfully accomplished what you have been looking for? Were you able to read ID3 tags? It would be great if you could share a snippet. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do a partial download: [Download file using partial download (HTTP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1798879/download-file-using-partial-download-http) (if the server supports it)

on rereading, and seeing joelhardi's comment, this is even easier:

```
jcomeau@intrepid:/tmp$ python
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Apr 20 2011, 11:58:30) 
[GCC 4.5.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import urllib
>>> urllib.urlopen('http://latest/temp.csv')
<addinfourl at 160617676 whose fp = <socket._fileobject object at 0x9872aec>>
>>> input=_
>>> input.read(128)
'gene,species,C_frame,start_exon1,end_exon1,start_exon2,end_exon2,start_exon3,end_exon3,start_exon4,end_exon4,intron1,intron2,int'
>>> input.close()
>>>
```