# How to parse only first 2 rows of csv with javascript

Tags: javascript, csv, papaparse

I am trying to only get first 2 rows of csv and I have no idea how to do it.This gets whole csv data.
Here is my code,

```
<script>
function arrayToTable(tableData) {
    var table = $('<table></table>');
    $(tableData).each(function (i, rowData) {
        var row = $('<tr></tr>');
        $(rowData).each(function (j, cellData) {
            row.append($('<td>'+cellData+'</td>'));
        });
        table.append(row);
    });
    return table;
}

$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "https://www.quandl.com/api/v3/datasets/LLOYDS/BSI.csv?api_key=xxxxxxxxx",
    success: function (data) {
        $('body').append(arrayToTable(Papa.parse(data).data));
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Do you know how many elements are in 1 row?

Comment: Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13704615/partially-download-a-file-with-javascript

Comment: Date               Index
9/20/2016 660
9/19/2016 661
9/16/2016 660
9/15/2016 661
9/14/2016 665
9/13/2016 671
9/12/2016 681

Comment: Use `split("\n")`, and then just take the first two results (or second and third if there's a header row).

Comment: @sideroxylon He doesn't want to download the whole data

Comment: Header is Date Idex row. then date and index values on every row.I am really bad on java. How do I use it and where do I implement it?

Comment: It can be whole document, not a big deal :) I just need latest date and index value to show :) cvs fıles are not that big.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change this code:

```
$(tableData).each(function (i, rowData) {
    var row = $('<tr></tr>');
```

By inserting an if line:

```
$(tableData).each(function (i, rowData) {
    if (i >= 2) return;
    var row = $('<tr></tr>');
```