# python: streaming httpRequest / loading website partially

Tags: python, http, streaming, web-crawler

I would like to know if there is a way in python to "stream" httpRequests in order to avoid loading the whole page.

What I´m currently doing to get the html data of a given url is this:

```
req = urllib2.Request(url)
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
return response.read()
```

This way I´m always loading the whole website, but since I only need a small part of it I´m using more bandwith then I need to. If I could stop loading the website after I found a specific value / expression, or even better if I could specify where to start / end loading the website eg. starting at character #3000 loading until #5000 I´d save a lot of bandwith.

thanks in advance
tschery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1798945/363949) shows how to do partial HTTP loading in Python. You can also use `response.read(N)` (N being the number of bytes to read) but there is no guarantee that the exact amount you specify is downloaded.

Comment: figured it out myself by now, but I appreciate your answer and I hope it helps others.