# Python: How to download file using range of bytes?

Tags: python, python-2.7, http-headers, http-protocols

I want to download file in multi thread mode and I have following code here:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import httplib


def main():
    url_opt = '/film/0d46e21795209bc18e9530133226cfc3/7f_Naruto.Uragannie.Hroniki.001.seriya.a1.20.06.13.mp4'

    headers = {}
    headers['Accept-Language'] = 'en-GB,en-US,en'
    headers['Accept-Encoding'] = 'gzip,deflate,sdch'
    headers['Accept-Charset'] = 'max-age=0'
    headers['Cache-Control'] = 'ISO-8859-1,utf-8,*'
    headers['Cache-Control'] = 'max-age=0'
    headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1)'
    headers['Connection'] = 'keep-alive'
    headers['Accept'] = 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml,*/*'
    headers['Range'] = ''

    conn = httplib.HTTPConnection('data09-cdn.datalock.ru:80')
    conn.request("GET", url_opt, '', headers)

    print "Request sent"

    resp = conn.getresponse()
    print resp.status
    print resp.reason
    print resp.getheaders()

    file_for_wirte = open('cartoon.mp4', 'w')
    file_for_wirte.write(resp.read())

    print resp.read()

    conn.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Here is output:

```
Request sent
200
OK
[('content-length', '62515220'), ('accept-ranges', 'bytes'), ('server', 'nginx/1.2.7'), ('last-modified', 'Thu, 20 Jun 2013 12:10:43 GMT'), ('connection', 'keep-alive'), ('date', 'Fri, 14 Feb 2014 07:53:30 GMT'), ('content-type', 'video/mp4')]
```

This code working perfectly however I do not understand through the documentation how to download file using ranges. If you see output of response, which server provides:

```
 ('content-length', '62515220'), ('accept-ranges', 'bytes')
```

It supports range in 'bytes' unit where content size is 62515220

However in this request whole file downloaded. But what I want to do first obtain server information like does this file can be supported using http range queries and content size of file with out downloading? And how I can create http query with range (i.e.: 0~25000)?

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8293687/2319400

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1798879/download-file-using-partial-download-http Different library, but should get you on the right track.

Comment: @sebastian Thank you for your comment. I already saw this answer. Moreover I capture packets using wireshark. However it is not clear how to detect does server support range selection. I mean is there method to check does file can be download using range selection or not? There is applications which support multi thread downloading with range selection however if server does not support it still tries to download files in other threads (i.e., flashgot, reget and etc.). However how i can obtain server or file information where I can lookup range support information?

Comment: @pi. Thank you for your comment. If functionality which is not provided by `httplib` will not be enough I will defiantly use the library which supports it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Pass [`Range`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.35) header with `bytes=start_offset-end_offset` as range specifier.

For example, following code retrieve the first 300 bytes. (`0-299`):

```
>>> import httplib
>>> conn = httplib.HTTPConnection('localhost')
>>> conn.request("GET", '/', headers={'Range': 'bytes=0-299'}) # <----
>>> resp = conn.getresponse()
>>> resp.status
206
>>> resp.status == httplib.PARTIAL_CONTENT
True
>>> resp.getheader('content-range')
'bytes 0-299/612'
>>> content = resp.read()
>>> len(content)
300
```

**NOTE** Both `start_offset`, `end_offset` are inclusive.

**UPDATE**

If the server does not understand `Range` header, it will respond with the status code 200 (`httplib.OK`) instead of 206 (`httplib.PARTIAL_CONTENT`), and it will send whole content. To make sure the server respond partial content, check the status code.

```
>>> resp.status == httplib.PARTIAL_CONTENT
True
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I really appreciate you quick response. I will accept your answer. And one more thing is it possible to detect does server support or not range selection for downloading or not?

Comment: @Phoenix, If the server does not support `Range` header, it will respond with 200 (`httplib.OK`) status code instead of 206 (`httplib.PARTIAL_CONTENT`). So check the status code as shown in the example code: `resp.status == httplib.PARTIAL_CONTENT`

Comment: Thank you for clarification I will upvote your answer tomorrow because you reach your daily limit today. :)

Comment: And please if you can just extend your answer with little bit explanation it will be helpful others with out reading comments. Thank you.

Comment: @Phoenix, I thought `>>> resp.status == httplib.PARTIAL_CONTENT` in the answer was enough. I updated the answer with explanation as you suggested. Thank you for the comment.

Comment: @Expolarity, This answer's purpose is to download partial content, not inspect whether it's possible. Using HEAD will not download content.

Comment: You could also check that the `Accept-Ranges` header exists and is `bytes` (as opposed to `none`).