# How to successfully download range of bytes instead of complete file using python?

Tags: python, http

I am trying to download only range of bytes of a file and I am trying the following process:

`r = requests.get('https://stackoverflow.com', headers={'Range':'bytes=0-999'})`

But it give status code 200 as opposed to 206 and I am getting the entire file.

I tried following this [Python: How to download file using range of bytes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21775860/python-how-to-download-file-using-range-of-bytes) but it also gave me status code 200. What is the reason and how do I download files partially using python?

Headers for stackoverflow:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Last-Modified: Fri, 04 Aug 2017 05:28:29 GMT
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-Request-Guid: 86fd186e-b5ac-472f-9d79-c45149343776  
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15552000
Content-Length: 107699
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Date: Wed, 06 Sep 2017 11:48:16 GMT
Via: 1.1 varnish
Age: 0
Connection: keep-alive
X-Served-By: cache-sin18023-SIN
X-Cache: MISS
X-Cache-Hits: 0
X-Timer: S1504698496.659820,VS0,VE404
Vary: Fastly-SSL
X-DNS-Prefetch-Control: off
Set-Cookie: prov=6df82a45-2405-b1dd-1430-99e27827b360; domain=.stackoverflow.com; expires=Fri, 01-Jan-2055 00:00:00 GMT; path=/; HttpOnly
Cache-Control: private
```

Answer (score 2):

This requires server-side support.  Probably the server does not support it.

To find out, make a HEAD request and see if the response has `Accept-Ranges`.

Comment: In the header, I can see Accept-Ranges: bytes and according to https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-14.5 , it means partial downloading is supported

Comment: What's the actual URL you're using?

Comment: @johnZwink,  its stack overflow in his post.

Comment: I am using stackoverflow.com. Does it work for you with stackoverflow.com ?

Comment: @Krash `HEAD https://stackoverflow.com` will get `Accept-Ranges` as `bytes`. However, when send range request, `200 OK` and the whole html file is returned.

Comment: I suspect what's happening is the server supports range requests only for certain files (e.g. images), not for everything.

Comment: @JohnZwinck I don't think that is the case. When I do a partial get to stackoverflow.com/ , if it wasn't possible to download it partially, this request's header wouldn't contain Accept-Ranges, but it did.